# Error in Creating Java array with Multiple Data Types

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, object

Can someone please explain why it doesn't work? The error is at `obj[0][0]=1;`. It says that GPA can't be converted to int, same thing for `String` variable assignment `s`.

```java
public class GPA {        
        public String s;
        public int n;
        public GPA[][] a;

        //constructor
        public GPA(GPA[][] a){}    

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            GPA[][] obj=new GPA[2][2];
            obj[0][0]=1; //error here
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes the error is correct. You can't convert like that.

Comment: In java, you can not have multiple data types within an array. If you declare the array as an array of GPA objects, it must only include GPA objects. If you declare the array as an int array, it must only include int's.

Comment: @SureshAtta How can I do it then?

Comment: @KylonTyner I did create obj as GPA object.

Comment: @Maya Yes, you did. However, you are trying to store an int in the GPA array when you call "obj[0]=1;" You instead need to do something like "obj[0] = new GPA(string, int);" where string and int are populated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work and gives you compile time error because GPA is class type and you are trying to assigning int value to it.

You have two options.

**Option 1:**

```
GPA[] obj = new GPA[4];
obj[0] = new GPA();
obj[0].n = 1;
```

**Option 2:**

You can make members of GPA private and use setters to set the value. Below is example.

```
public class GPA {

    private String s;
    private int n;
    private GPA[] a;

    public GPA() {}

    public GPA(GPA[] a) {}

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }

    public void setN(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public GPA[] getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(GPA[] a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

and then set using setter.

```
obj[0].setN(1);
```

It's not good programming practice to make your members public. It is always advised to use setters.

Comment: Wouldn't that give a NullPointerException on your first line, in both cases?

Answer (score 4):

`obj` is an Array of GPA objects.
`obj[0] = 1` means you are assigning the first element of that array to an `int`value. It should be an `object` of type GPA.
You can do it like

```java
obj[0] = new GPA("John Doe", 6);
```

I would also recommend using Java convention, by making `variables` private and `set()` them by public methods like `setter()`s.

**The question is changed which makes the answer irrelevant.**

Comment: As would I recoment lombok @Data, but it is kind of irelevant, given that even the dummy contructor makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

What you're actualy doing is trying to assign int and/or string to variable that is expecting object of GPA class.
Didn't you want to do

```
obj[0].n=1;
obj[0].s="text;"
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give a `NullPointerException` on your first line?

Comment: Well, if You take it in relation to source code provided, npe would be the least of problems, what I meant is more of a way to properly assign values to their designated variables.

Answer (score 1):

For array of object you always have to create on object at that position first. otherwise you alway get a `NullPointerException`.
So what you need goes something like this

```
 GPA[][] obj = new GPA[2][2];
obj[0][0] = new GPA();
obj[0][0].s="text";
obj[0][0].n=1;
...
```

and so on for every position there is.

Answer (score 0):

Java Arrays are homogeneous(Javascript arrays are heterogeneous). That means you can only store the type of elements which you used while creating an Array.

```
ex: `int intArray[];` //We can store only int type elements(it also accepts Integer etc.. types but java converts to int then store it)
```

Now, apply the same rule to `public GPA[] a;` here a is an array of type GPA. So it accept only GPA type object.

That mean, you can store values like as below

a[0] = new GPA("nameHere", 6);

> If I want to store either a string or an int, one at a time( I have
>   to make table of Student Name vs GPA) ,how do I do it?

One solution to this requirement is, assign a variable using constructor or setter method.

```
GPA[] obj = new GPA[2];

obj[0] = new GPA("first", 6); // here you need to create a new constructor
or 
obj[1] = new GPA(); // Here default constructor will work and you need to have setter methods

obj[1].setName("second");
```

Hope this help...